# can't upload images using react to backend using axios and nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I try to upload a photo from React and save it in a public folder on the backend and then display the filename in the MySql database

After trying it through Postman, the photo has been successfully uploaded and appears and produces a json like this

```
{"image":"/img/14d714a9ed97fb92db657b9518e89a1e.png",
"id_produk":23,
"id_user":19,
"Nama_toko":"Nihongo Mantappu",
"Nama_Produk":"Butter",
"Deskripsi":"Mentega Blueband 50g",
"Price":5000,
"Jumlah_stock":7},
```

but when I tried it in React it only produced this

```
{"image":"/img/",
"id_produk":29,
"id_user":19,
"Nama_toko":"Nihongo Mantappu",
"Nama_Produk":"Beras Cinajur",
"Deskripsi":"Beras Cianjur 1kg",
"Price":500000,"Jumlah_stock":20}
```

so that when i check the database on the image it becomes empty

here the code for upload image

```
import React from 'react'
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import NavbarPenjual from '../../Component/NavbarPenjual';
import {addproduk} from '../../View/UserFunctions';
import { Form,Col, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';


class TambahProduk extends React.Component{
    
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state={
            id_user:'',
            Nama_toko:'',
            Nama_produk: '',
            Harga:'',
            image: '',
            Deskripsi: '',
            Jumlah_produk: '',
            error:{}
        }
        this.onChange=this.onChange.bind(this)
        this.onSubmit=this.onSubmit.bind(this)
    }
    onChange(e){
        this.setState({[e.target.name]:e.target.value})
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        const token = localStorage.getItem('usertoken')
        const decoded= token ? jwt_decode(token) : null;
        this.setState({
            id_user:decoded.id_user,
            Nama_toko:decoded.Nama_toko
        })
    }
    onSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        const newProduk={
            id_user:this.state.id_user,
            Nama_toko:this.state.Nama_toko,
            Nama_Produk: this.state.Nama_Produk,
            Price:this.state.Price,
            image: this.state.image,
            Deskripsi: this.state.Deskripsi, 
            Jumlah_stock: this.state.Jumlah_stock,
        }
        console.log(newProduk)
        addproduk(newProduk).then(res =>{
            //localStorage.setItem('usertoken',res.data.token);
            this.props.history.push(`/DashboardPenjual`)
                }).catch(err=>{
                    console.log(err)
                    alert("gagal")
            })
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <NavbarPenjual/>
                
                <Form className="container"style={{marginTop:28}}  noValidate onSubmit={this.onSubmit}> 
                    <h2>Tambah Produk</h2>
                    <Form.Row controlId="exampleForm.ControlInput1">
                        <Form.Label column lg={2}>
                            Nama Produk  
                        </Form.Label>
                        <br/>
                        <Col>
                            <Form.Control 
                            type="text" 
                            placeholder="Masukan Nama Produk"
                            name="Nama_Produk"
                            value={this.state.Nama_Produk}
                            onChange={this.onChange}
                            />
                        </Col>
                    </Form.Row>
                    <br/> 
                    <Form.Row controlId="exampleForm.ControlInput1">
                        <Form.Label column lg={2}>
                            Harga Produk 
                        </Form.Label>
                        <br/>
                        <Col>
                            <Form.Control type="text" 
                            placeholder="Masukan Harga Produk"
                            name="Price"
                            value={this.state.Price}
                            onChange={this.onChange}
                            />
                        </Col>
                    </Form.Row>
                    <br/>
                    <Form.Row controlId="exampleForm.ControlInput1">
                        <Form.Label column lg={2}>
                            Jumlah Produk
                        </Form.Label>
                        <br/>
                        <Col>
                            <Form.Control 
                            type="text" 
                            placeholder="Masukan Jumlah Produk"
                            name="Jumlah_stock"
                            value={this.state.Jumlah_stock}
                            onChange={this.onChange}
                            />
                        </Col>
                    </Form.Row>
                    <br/>
                    <Form.Row controlId="exampleForm.ControlInput1">
                        <Col>
                        <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1">
                            <Form.Label>Deskripsi Produk</Form.Label>
                            <br/>
                            <Form.Control 
                            as="textarea" 
                            rows="3"
                            name="Deskripsi"
                            value={this.state.Deskripsi}
                            onChange={this.onChange}
                            />
                        </Form.Group>    
                        </Col>
                    </Form.Row>
                    <br/>
                    <Form.Row controlId="exampleForm.ControlInput1">
                        <Form.Group>
                        <Form.File 
                        id="exampleFormControlFile1" 
                        label="Masukan Foto Produk" 
                        type="image"
                        name="image"
                        value={this.state.image}
                        onChange={this.onChange}
                        />
                        </Form.Group>
                    </Form.Row>
                    <br/>
                    <button 
                        type="submit"
                        className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
                    >Submit</button>
                    <Form.Row controlId="exampleForm.ControlInput1" style={{ visibility: "hidden" }}>
                        <Col>
                        <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlInput1">
                            <br/>
                            <Form.Control 
                            as="text" 
                            name="id_user"
                            value={this.state.id_user}
                            onChange={this.onChange}
                            />
                        </Form.Group>    
                        </Col>
                    </Form.Row>
                    <Form.Row controlId="exampleForm.ControlInput1" style={{ visibility: "hidden" }}>
                        <Col>
                        <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1">
                            <br/>
                            <Form.Control disabled
                            as="area" 
                            name="Nama_toko"
                            value={this.state.Nama_toko}
                            onChange={this.onChange}
                            />
                        </Form.Group>    
                        </Col>
                    </Form.Row>

                </Form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default TambahProduk;
```

this is part of the axios userfuction for add product

```
    export const addproduk = newProduk =>{
    return axios
    .post('product/addproduk',{
        id_user:newProduk.id_user,
        Nama_toko:newProduk.Nama_toko,
        Nama_Produk:newProduk.Nama_Produk,
        image: newProduk.image,
        Deskripsi:newProduk.Deskripsi,
        Price:newProduk.Price,
        Jumlah_stock:newProduk.Jumlah_stock
    })
    .then(res=>{
        console.log("produk di tambahkan")
        return res
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
        return err;
    })
}
```

How do I get uploaded like when I use Postman?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image is not an value, it's a file. So, in the onChange function you assigned the image.target.name as value

Try like this :

```
event.target.name === "image"? event.target.files[0] : event.target.value;
```

Comment: what should I put in the event? because there is an error like this src/View/Penjual/TambahProduk.js
  Line 28:9:   Unexpected use of 'event'                                       
  Line 28:9:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Comment: const handleChange = (event) => {
    const value =
      event.target.name === "image"
        ? event.target.files[0]
        : event.target.value;
    setValues({
      ...values,
      error: false,
      [event.target.name]: value,
    });
  };       (Its in functional components tho,you can change it to class)

Comment: still cant uploading the image, the result still {"image":"/img/",

Comment: Once check the network tab in the console whether the problem is with the frontend or the backend